# chrome.debugger.attach will throw an error when attach to a new tab

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, tabs

As chrome.experimental.debugger APIs have been moved to chrome.debugger APIs, I use these kinds of APIs to collect network information, and I need to use chrome.debugger.attach before the tab navigation(a new created tab).
The older chrome.experimental.debugger.acttach worked well, but now it will throw an error("Can not attach to the page with the "chrome://" scheme.) after this API is changed to chrome.debugger.acttach.
The chrome version that I use is - 18.0.1003.1 dev-m.
The test extension code is from the chrome sample(http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/samples.html#debugger).

Anyone know the reason about "chrome.debugger.attach" API throwing the error?

Answer (score 1):

This change was intentional, see Chrome issue # 108519

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108519#c2

I opened defect #110019 asking for the change to be reversed.  If you're impacted by this change please add comments and/or star the issue:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110019

As a workaround, I added code in our extension that detects when we're about to try and attach to a tab with a URL of chrome://newtab, and moves the tab's location to a new blank HTML file in our extension.  Then we're allowed to attach to it.  Note the extension ID is specific to your extension.

`if (tab.url == "chrome://newtab")
    {
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "chrome-extension://<id here>/blank.html"});
    }`

HTH
Nathan

Comment: The new bug is "WontFix", so I'd say the workaround I describe above is now the recommended hoop-jumping pattern for attaching to new tabs.